# How can I find the least rect, which contains all points or the point symmetrical to the y=x axis?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

I have a set of points (x,y). How can I find the smallest rectangle (edges are perpendicular to the axis of the coordinate system) that contains these points or points symmetrical to the y=x axis? Not all the points have to be mirror images at the same time, so it is possible to have some normal and some symmetrical points to the original ones.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to calculate a 2D bounding rectangle? Just loop through each point in your set and get the min and max value for each component and you will have a bounding rectangle.

Comment: No; he's asking for an axis-aligned boundingrect, BUT with the option to replace arbitrarily many points in the set by their mirrored counterparts. That's the challenge.

Comment: @ThorngardSO that's not a challenge. The smallest rectangle can always easily be produced by mirroring all points such that they are distributed over a single quadrant, if the symmetry is axial or two quadrants, if it's point-symmetry.

Comment: @Paul I just had a similar suspicion, but was not at all sure about it. But if it is the case, post it as an answer!

Comment: Smallest x*y or smallest x+y?

Comment: @ThorngardSO is right. It`s challenge. 
@stark 2x+2y
@Paul i have to take point or point symmetrical to the y=x axis (this operation for each of points from the set), but edges are perpendicular to the axis of the coordinate system.

Comment: Is the brute-force `O(n*2^n)` approach acceptable? :0)

Comment: @dfri Unfortunately not. I am looking for a better solution which will be faster and (if its possible) have a lower complexity.

Comment: @WojtekPrzechodzeń Note that it might be possible that this problem is NP-hard, in which case you will have a hard time finding a solution that runs better than, say `O(2^n)`. However I'm not certain about this NP-hard property, but writing this up as a formal optimization problem would yield a program with binary variables; a subset of mixed integer programming (MIP) problems, which are, NP-hard.

Comment: @dfri No, because I found better brute-force solution. We have to get all of these points (original and mirrored) and create all possible rects (2n * 2n * 2n * 2n). Its O(n^4). Then we need to check which rects contain all of points (its O(n)) and save rect if its smaller then last found. Now i`m working on 0(n^2) solution but i know from my lecturer that 0(n) is also possible.

Comment: @WojtekPrzechodzeń That's nice! Please add your answer here (as an answer) once your done, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* solve this using the brute-force `O(n*2^n)` approach: define your points as some class/structure which, in addition to the `(x,y)` coordinates of your point, also holds a boolean `mirrored` state. For `n` number of points, loop over all the `2^n` possible set of states of this set of points. For each set of states, calculate the circumference (`2x+2y`) of the bounding rectangle.

Below follows this solution implemented in Swift. If you choose to use this brute-force approach, hopefully you can translate it into your language of choice.

---

Point container and help functions:

```
struct Point {
    private var xOrig : Double
    private var yOrig : Double
    private var mirrored = false
    var x : Double { return mirrored ? yOrig : xOrig }
    var y : Double { return mirrored ? xOrig : yOrig }

    init(_ x: Double, _ y: Double) {
        xOrig = x
        yOrig = y
    }

    mutating func setState(state: Bool) {
        mirrored = state
    }
}

func boundingBoxCircumference(points: [Point]) -> Double {
    let xMax = points.maxElement { $0.x < $1.x }?.x ?? 0.0
    let xMin = points.minElement { $0.x < $1.x }?.x ?? 0.0
    let yMax = points.maxElement { $0.y < $1.y }?.y ?? 0.0
    let yMin = points.minElement { $0.y < $1.y }?.y ?? 0.0

    return 2*((xMax - xMin) + (yMax - yMin))
}

func setMirroredStates(inout points: [Point], states: [Bool]) {
    for i in 0..<points.count {
        points[i].setState(states[i])
    }
}
```

Main function and an example

```
func findSmallestBox(var points: [Point]) -> Double {
    var smallestBox = Double.infinity
    for i in 0..<Int(pow(2,Double(points.count))) {
        smallestBox = min(smallestBox, boundingBoxCircumference(points))

        var binString = String(i, radix: 2)
        if let a = Optional(points.count - binString.characters.count) where a > 0 {
            binString = "".stringByPaddingToLength(a, withString: "0", startingAtIndex: 0) + binString
        }
        let pointStates = Array(binString.characters).map { String($0) == "1" }

        setMirroredStates(&points, states: pointStates)
    }
    return smallestBox
}

var myPoints : [Point] = [Point(1,2), Point(-4,3), Point(7,-5), Point(5,4), Point(-5, -1)]
print(findSmallestBox(myPoints)) // 34
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but unfortunately i knew about brute-force solutions. I am looking for a better solution since 0(n*2^n) is to much.

Comment: @WojtekPrzechodzeń I see, perhaps someone else can come up with something.